# Venn diagram of $A \cup B = B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have to draw 3 Venn diagrams. A $\cup$ B = B. B $\cap$ A = B. B - A = B. I understand how to shade all of these, but I do not understand what "= B" is in any of these. I've searched and can't find any examples with = B.

Comment: If you take B as the empty set? It works for   B ∩ A = B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"= B" means that the shaded part will be exactly the set B. The pictures below can help you.

[image]

Shade the union of the circles in the first picture and shade the intersection of the circles in the second. In this case, what is the color of B?

Comment: In the second picture B is red? I don't understand what the "=" sign means when making Venn diagrams. A $\cup$ B = B mean the union of A and B is B?

Comment: @theguy1991 Yes, is red. Yes, A ∪ B = B means that the union is B. Notice that for this to happen, the set A have to be inside of the set B.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably you know how to draw a Venn diagram for $A$ and $B$ under the assumption, for example, that $A\subseteq B$.

Now suppose you know $A\cup B=B$. What does that tell you about the relationship between $A$ and $B$? Can you convert the statement "$A\cup B=B$" into a statement about $\subseteq$, which would let you draw a Venn diagram?